# IntelliJ does not generate WSDL from Java Code using Apache Axis 2

Tags: soap, wsdl, apache-axis, jetbrains-ide

I'm trying generate a WSDL from java code with Apache Axis2 using IntelliJ (latest and greatest version of ultimate), but the following screen just jiggles for a few seconds and nothing happens. Does this actually work? My web service is a simple "echo" service... :(

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In order to make Axis2 WSDL generation work you will need to:

1. Download Axis2 Binary Distribution from https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/download.html
2. On Intellij open `Settings > Tools > Web Services`
3. Configure Apache Axis 2 path to where you extracted the previously downloaded binaries

[image]

Now the `Generate Java Code From Wsdl` with option `Apache Axis 2` should work fine.